# List Comprehension python?

Tags: python

I have a function like this:

```
  for product in responseSoup.findAll("offersummary"):
        try:
            if product.lowestnewprice.formattedprice != None:
                price.append(product.lowestnewprice.formattedprice.text)
            else:
                price.append("")
        except:
            price.append("")
```

I am confused how to do the if/else statement with the try/except block? Will list comprehension speed up efficiency?

```
   [product.lowestnewprice.formattedprice for product in responseSoup.findAll("offersummary")]
```

Comment: Use `is not None` for comparison with `None` and don't use `try..except`. Except specific Exception classes

Comment: How about this atrocious one-liner: `price = ['' if product.get(lowestnewprice).get(formattedprice).get(text) is None else product.lowestnewprice.formattedprice.text for product in responseSoup.findAll("offersummary")]`.

Comment: @pzp close but sometimes lowestnewprice isnt even in there? so not too sure.  (Pdb) product.lowestnewprice.formattedprice
*** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'formattedprice'

Comment: @Ben Arrggg... Try this `price = ['' if product.get(lowestnewprice, {}).get(formattedprice, {}).get(text) is None else product.lowestnewprice.formattedprice.text for product in responseSoup.findAll("offersummary")]`.

Comment: @pzp thanks. Overall does list comprehension make it more efficient?

Comment: @Ben It's probably a little bit more efficient, but, as you can probably see, is quite a bit less readable. (And "write-able", as it took me two tries to get right :).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very readable solution:

```
prices = []
for product in responseSoup.findAll("offersummary"):
    price = product.get(lowestnewprice, {}).get(formattedprice, {}).get(text)
    if price is not None:
        prices.append(price)        
    else:
        prices.append('')
```

If you really don't care about readability, here's a very atrocious looking one-liner:

```
price = [''
         if product.get(lowestnewprice, {}).get(formattedprice, {}).get(
             text) is None else
         product.lowestnewprice.formattedprice.text
         for product in responseSoup.findAll("offersummary")]
```

They do essentially the same thing, but, in my opinion, the more readable solution is better.

**EDIT**

I just figured out a much better one-liner:

```
price = [product.get(lowestnewprice,{}).get(formattedprice,{}).get(text) or ''
         for product in responseSoup.findAll("offersummary")]
```

It's still less readable than the "very readable" solution, but it is not too bad. Now the decision really comes down to a matter of your preference.

Answer (score 0):

`try` and `except` blocks are used to see if the following code works. If not and it matches the given error, run that block of code. Else, run the other line of code. For example:

```
try:
    m = raw_input("Please enter an integer")
    n = int(m)
except ValueError:
    print "Invalid number"
else:
    print n
```

So, the program attempts to assign `m` the input from the user. Then `n` is assigned the input as an integer. Now the error chosen is `ValueError` since if `m` is a string, the conversion to `n` will raise that error. If it does, then it does the code in the `except` block, which is to print "Invalid number". If the conversion is successful, then print `n`.

Now with your program, you will try the `if` and `else` block. If the code doesn't work and it raises the error given in the `except` block, it will do `price.append("")`. Else, it will run the code in the `else` block, which you don't have. You need the `else:` to work in your `try/except` block for it to work including a specified error after the keyword `except` in your `except` statement.